# Call sql script using bat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, cmd, scripting

It is necessary to use the bat file to call the sql script and pass two variables into it, but sql complains about them. Asks to declare scalars.

Here is the bat file itself.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo SET @arg1 := %2, @arg2 := %3; > commands
copy /b commands + %1 + %2 > nul
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -S DESKTOP-OQ8JGR5 -U SA -P 123 -i %1
```

And sql script.

```
USE MVA
SELECT sum(number*price2 - number*price1) AS pribil FROM sale,goods
WHERE id=goods AND datepart(month, date)=@arg1 AND shop=@ar2
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Our homework is like this :(

Comment: In 2020... I'm shocked...

Comment: This is a Russian university. Cruel and merciless.

Comment: Type into a Command Prompt window `set /?` and `copy /?` and learn the correct syntax...

Answer (score 1):

you can create a stored procedure and call that via sqlcmd from the bat file. for example:

```
create procedure [SP_count_up]
(
@input int
)
as
begin
    select @input + 1
end
go
```

and call it in you bat file via

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec dbo.SP_count_up @input=3" -S <server> -d <database>
```